# Compute Limit $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-\lambda)^k}=1$

Tags: probability, limits

In order to show that a sequence of binomial distributed random variables $X_n \sim  B(n, \frac{\lambda}{n})$ converges weakly to a Poisson distributed random variable $X \sim Poi(\lambda)$, I want to show that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n=k)= \mathbb{P}(X = k) $ for each $k \in \mathbb{N} $ (I have already proved this).

So starting with 
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n=k)= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} {{n}\choose{k}} \left(\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^k \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^{n-k} = \dots = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left( \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^n \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-\lambda)^k}\right) $$

I know that the first factor is $e^{-\lambda}$ if you let $n \rightarrow \infty$, but I don't know how the second factor 
$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-\lambda)^k}$ is $1$.
Wolfram Alpha does not have any step-by-step solutions for this limit, so I hope you can help me.

Comment: Try to use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: $$(n-k+1)^k\le\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\le n^k$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that $(n-\lambda)^k$ is asymptotically equivalent to $n^k$ for $n\to\infty$.

Thus, the second factor can be written as $\frac{{n!}/(n-k)!}{n^k}$.
Using Prof. Vector's comment, we get:
$$\frac{(n-k+1)^k}{n^k}\le\frac{{n!}/(n-k)!}{n^k}\le1.$$
By noting that $(n-k+1)^k$ is asymptotically equivalent to $n^k$, we acquire
$$\underset{n\to\infty}\lim \frac{(n-k+1)^k}{n^k}=1.$$
Altogether, using the inequality above, this proves that 
$$\underset{n\to\infty}\lim\frac{{n!}/(n-k)!}{(n-\lambda)^k}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply observe that 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-\lambda)^k}
&=\frac{n(n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n-k+1)}{(n-\lambda)^k}
\\
&= \frac{n^k+\alpha_k n^{k-1}+\ldots +\alpha_0}{n^k- n^{k-1}\lambda+\ldots +(-1)^k\lambda^k}
\\
&=\frac{1+\frac{\alpha_k}{n}+\ldots +\frac{\alpha_0}{n^k}}{1-\frac{\lambda}{n}+\ldots +\frac{(-1)^k\lambda^k}{n^k}}
\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\color{red}{1}
\end{align}
$$
because the two polynomials have the same degree and the same leading term.